# find does not work with my variable

Tags: bash, scripts, find

I'm trying to find the number of dirs and files in a given dir.  I'm running my bash script like this:

```
ARCHIVE=/path/to/archive ./myScript
```

in my script I am doing this:

```
#find the number of non-empty directories in the given dir 
dirs=$(find $ARCHIVE -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d | wc -l)
#find the number of files in the given dir
msgs=$(find $ARCHIVE -type f | wc -l)

echo "Number of directories: $dirs"
echo "Total number of messages: $msgs"
```

This works great when I am running the script on a subset of the data I'm looking at, which is located in a dir at the same level as the script. However, the actual data is in someone else's directory and when I run it with the ARCHIVE variable set to that location, both values return as 0. I have a similar script that I use as well, and the find command there does not work on the second directory either.  Strangely enough, I use some egrep commands and they work just fine for both.

Why can I not use find in this manner?

Comment: did you try running your script with `bash -x` so it shows you debugging information and variable expansion?

Comment: yes, the variable expands to the correct location, and nothing looks out of the ordinary

Comment: I would surround `$ARCHIVE` with double quotes, like this: `find "$ARCHIVE" -min...`. Also make sure you have permission to access the other person's data.

Comment: Just to clarify, your `ARCHIVE` variable is specifying two directories for find to look in. One is `/path/to/archive`, the other is `./myScript`. So `find` will look in those two directories. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @ladaghini double quotes didn't change anything, and since grep works, I assume I have access?  Do I need more than read access to those files?

Comment: @roadmr ./myScript is a bash script, it runs that script which references $ARCHIVE

Comment: a shot in the dark, try `ARCHIVE=wherever; ./myScript` ( notice the semicolon)

Comment: @roadmr strange, I tried that and not matter what directory I use, I get dirs=1 msgs=40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the directory you want to search as a parameter to the bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# First argument to script shall be directory in which to search
ARCHIVE=$1 

#find the number of non-empty directories in the given dir 
dirs=$(find "$ARCHIVE" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d | wc -l)
#find the number of files in the given dir
msgs=$(find "$ARCHIVE" -type f | wc -l)

echo "Number of directories: $dirs"
echo "Total number of messages: $msgs"
```

Running the script, called `dirfiles`, on my home directory:

```
$ ./dirfiles ~
Number of directories: 27
Total number of messages: 8703
```

And on `/usr/lib`:

```
$ ./dirfiles /usr/lib
Number of directories: 161
Total number of messages: 9630
```

Furthermore, `find` offers three ways to resolve symbolic links:

- `-P`: don't follow symbolic links
- `-L`: follow symbolic links
- `-H`: don't follow symbolic links except when processing command line arguments.

If you don't want to follow symlinks, but `$ARCHIVE` happens to be one, then perhaps `-H` is the way to go.

Comment: Still did not work, I'm almost positive this is an issue of permissions somehow.  Is there a way to figure out what permissions are needed to use find?  As seen in the comments of @Radu's answer, I don't see why those permissions would be insufficient to run find.

Comment: Have you tried running, e.g., just `find /your/directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d` and verifying the output matches the numbers given by the script? Also, you need execute permission on a directory to search it.

Comment: so to verify, I would need execute permission to use find? That would be the issue if this is true.

Comment: You already have execute permission on `find`. I was adding as a FYI that if you want to search a directory, you need execute permission on it, but it seems you already have it based on your comment to the other answer. You can try the command `find ./your/directory -not -executable -type d` to list all directories that are not searchable.

Comment: Ok as per my comment to you on the other answer, it was a symbolic link. Added the -L flag to find, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Hm, it also seems that adding a / to the end of my archive path worked too.

Answer (score 1):

This is happen because probably you don't have read permissions in someone else's directory. If you don't have read permissions, you can't view/search/find any content. You can check this with the following command:

```
ls -l /home/username/directory
```

Also be sure that those files or directories for which you search are really files or directories (first character from 10 character string permission is `-` or `d`, *not something else* - `l` in your case which stands for symbolic links).

> `ls` shows permissions as a 10 character string, for example `-rw-r--r--`. The characters can be interpreted as `TUUUGGGOOO` where:
>
> ```
> T Type
> UUU   Rights for the owner of the file
> GGG   Rights for users in the group
> OOO   Rights for others, not listed above
> ```
>
> **T** is one of:
>
> ```
> - file
> d directory
> c character device
> b block device
> l symbolic link
> ```

Source: [Introduction to Unix file permissions](http://oldfield.wattle.id.au/luv/permissions.html)

Also, when you use:

- `find -type d` - you search only for directories.
- `find -type f` - you search only for regular files.

Comment: I do have read permission on that directory, I can use grep on it (which I believe implies that I do), and in fact using `ls -l` on it returned `rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: @turbo And for the files/folders inside that directory do you have read permissions? Can you see something if you navigate there?

Comment: The directory has about 200 directories and they are all set to `rwxr-x-r-x` and each directory has some files, I tested a few and they were all `r--r--r--`.

Comment: @turbo Then you should speak with that user. Maybe he set other special permission on his files. I'm sure that there is the problem with permissions. What is the output of this command: `ls -alR /home/username >/dev/null`?

Comment: @turbo When you say `ls -l` returned `rwxrwxrwx`, was there a `d` in front of that? Try `ls -dl ./your/directory` instead.

Comment: @ladaghini Hm there is an l actually, `lrwxrwxrwx`.  So a symbolic link.  Does find not work on symbolic links?

Comment: @turbo Ha! ...`l` is set for symbolic links. So that is not actually a file **and you search only for directories and/or files in your script**. See [Introduction to Unix file permissions](http://oldfield.wattle.id.au/luv/permissions.html) (search for  lrwx)

Comment: @turbo See my new edits at the answer.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Yep I figured that out myself from my last comment, but your answer explains it very well.  If you could add that adding the `-L` flag to `find` will solve the problem of symbolic links, I will definitely accept it.  I also found that adding a `/` to the end of my archive path made ls -dl return that it was a directory, but without it, a symbolic link.